# Hover in prepend() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="Wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="count">My Counter</div>
        <div class="background"></div>
        <div class="hover"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
<button class="AddDiv">AddDiv</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function(){
    $('.Wrap').prepend($('<div class="container"><div class="background"></div><div class="hover"></div></div>')); 
});

$(".background").on("mouseover", function () {
    $(".hover").fadeIn(500);
});

$(".hover").on("mouseout", function () {
    $(".hover").fadeOut(200);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mpd075s8/5/

Hello, I have problem with hover, look at the jsfiddle and click on button AddDiv and when hover on the green square hovered are all divs, but I would like that every div will be hovered separately. And hover doesn't work in new divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things

1. You need to use [delegated event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamic element
2. Use `this` for the reference of current element.

Try like following.

```js
$('.AddDiv').on('click', function() {
    $('.Wrap').prepend($('<div class="container"><div class="background"></div><div class="hover"></div></div>'));
});

$(".Wrap").on("mouseover", ".background", function () {
    $(this).next(".hover").fadeIn(500);
});

$(".Wrap").on("mouseout", ".hover", function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200);
});
```

```css
.Wrap {
  width: 650px;
  height: 800px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.AddDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.background {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 170px;
  top: 10px;
}

.hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1001;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="background">
    </div>
    <div class="hover">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class=AddDiv>AddDiv</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `$(this)` jquery function

```
$("body").on("mouseover",".background", function () {
    $(this).siblings('.hover').fadeIn(500);
});
$("body").on("mouseout",".hover", function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(200);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mpd075s8/7/

Comment: Post your solution as code in the answer and only use demo as support for what actually exists in answer